Limitation of bipolar ion exchange membrane
I have been recently using bipolar membrane in my project. However, I discovered a problem is that potassium ion seems leaking through the bipolar membrane and pass to the other side which only contains a small amount of potassium (a few ppm, checked before testing). Can bipolar membrane allows the flow of potassium ion? Is there any other ion that can pass through bipolar membrane?
